# GlassfishESB filebc component causes too many open file handles

Tags: file-io, glassfish-esb

I have an Glassfish ESB based CASA app running in production system (Win 2k3) for sometime now. I have recently encountered a very strange file handles related issue. It so happened that I was unable to perform any file related operations from inside the prod server. My analysis lead me to using the tool called "OpenedFilesView" which listed all open file handles for any process. I saw that there were thousands of file handles open for .LCK files on a specified folder (on a file server). This is the folder (say FolderB) into which my casa app tries to copy files that are received from a different folder (say FolderA). I have used FILEBC component for this file move operation. Has anyone faced this/similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am told that an upgrade to Glassfish ESB v 2.2 solves this issue. I am trying it now...